# Create a pre-publish husky hook similar to pre-commit

Tags: javascript, git, package.json, husky

I've had a look around but cant seem to find an answer, could be there isnt one so I'll double check that on here.

I want to create a hook in husky that runs pre-publish, currently I've got to run build then publish and I'm just looking to streamline this if possible.

I dont think you'll need anything else from me but let me know if you do.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE ------------------------------------

Could I create a custom script that calls build and publish?

Something like this in package.json?

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "yarn build && yarn publish"
}
```